# Finding the last $4$ digits of a huge computation such as $2^{3^{4^5}}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Finding the last digits of $2^{1024}$ is a trivial task with computers $(7216)$, but this gets considerably harder the bigger the powers and base get.

For example $18231^{1024}$ is still doable $(5921)$ but what if I wanted to find the last digits of $2^{3^{4^5}}$? This is obviously impossible to compute (or would take an exceedingly long time).

How would one solve this problem?

Also, I'm not quite sure which category this would fall under.

Comment: For power towers there are also methods as long as the modulus is small. So, it is not true that the mentioned modulo calculation cannot be done in a reasoanle amount of time. We do not need the actual value of the power tower for modulo calculations.

Answer (score 1):

Perform all calculations modulo $10000$, and it should be relatively straightforward to compute with binary exponentiation.

The answer is $0352$ (the last 4 numbers).

In general, to find the last $n$ numbers, perform calculations modulo $10^n$.

Answer (score 0):

Remember Cyclicity of 2.  (2 ⟹ 4 ⟹ 8 ⟹ 6)
So to find $\displaystyle 2{^{3}}^{4^{5}}$ all you need to do is find $\displaystyle 3{^{4}}^{5} mod\ 4$  ⟹ $\displaystyle ( -1){^{4}}^{5} mod\ 4\ =\ 1\bmod 4$
So the last digit of this number is 2.

Comment: Quick Comment: This method works in general where if you are finding the last digit of a number ending with $a$. you find its cyclicity $b$, then you find the modulo of the exponent $p$ with base of cyclicity  ($p_.mod_.b$).

Comment: I'm sorry, but I'm not familiar with this method at all. Could you send some references?

Comment: OP appears to be looking for the last four digits of some number, not just the last digit.

Comment: @avighnac Have a look at this question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1955616/how-do-i-find-the-last-digits-of-large-numbers-using-modular-arithmetic